# I want to add a class to an element using event listener but it does not work properly

Tags: javascript, event-handling

the event listener can alter z-index but does not add the class hide to the element I want. you can see the code below

```
choicesBtns.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    choicesBtns.classList.add("hide");
    choicesBtns.style.zIndex = '-1';
    selection.style.zIndex = "+1";
    selection.classList.remove('hide');


})
```

the HTML is below

```
<div class="display">
      <div class="choice-btns">
        <button class="btn paper" value="paper"></button>
        <button class="btn scissors" value="scissors"></button>
        <button class="btn rock" value="rock"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="selection hide">
        <div class="choices">
        <div class="player">
          <button class="btn" value=""></button>
          <p>You Picked</p>
          </div>
          <div class="house">
          <button class="btn" value=""></button>
          <p>The House Picked</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-result winner">
        <p class="result">You win</p>
        <button>Play Again</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well

Comment: @AbitoPrakash I have added the html too